# Start a storyboard from code-behind (xaml.cs), not from view model MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, storyboard, code-behind

In WPF I have set below style for a border:

```
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="BorderBlinking">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PopupBlinking}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>                                
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" SpeedRatio="3" RepeatBehavior="3x" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and I attach to the border like this:

```
<Border Grid.Row="2" x:Name="popup" 
        Style="{StaticResource BorderBlinking}"
        CornerRadius="10,10,0,0" Height="25" Margin="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        BorderBrush="DarkBlue" BorderThickness="1"
        Background="AntiqueWhite">
    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="Common.Images;component/Images/Info.png" Height="20" Width="20" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
       Background="Transparent" FontSize="12"><Run Text="this is a custom popup"/></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Then from my code behind (not view model) I want to start the storyboard. I know how to start it from view model through a property "PopupBlinking" (as above in the example) bound to the datatrigger but now I need to know how to start it from code-behind (not view model).

I have modified code above and done below:

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="Blink" >
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                                 To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" SpeedRatio="3" RepeatBehavior="3x" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="1" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
        </Storyboard>
```

and from code-behind:

```
        Storyboard sb = Resources["Blink"] as Storyboard;            
        sb.Begin(this.popup);
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: That means you don't need the whole DataTrigger stuff? And just want to start an Opacity animation on a Border element?

Comment: Yes, I have modified the code, see my update. Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could directly start an animation like this:

```
popup.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = 0,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5),
        AutoReverse = true,
        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever
    });
```

Comment: Great! I like it.